# Send data to a web metod in web service from a form in windows phone 7 application

Tags: c#, forms, windows-phone-7

I am building an app for windows phone 7 where i have a form with the following text fields and 1 radio button. The name of the text fields in the form are:

name, age, sadd, cadd, eadd, phn, zip. The xaml for the radio button is:

```
 <TextBlock Canvas.Left="20" Canvas.Top="157" Height="44" Name="gen" Text="Gender" Foreground="Black" FontFamily="Verdana" FontSize="24" Width="134" />
 <RadioButton Canvas.Left="139" Canvas.Top="157" FontStyle="Italic" GroupName="Gender" Foreground="Black" Content="Male" Height="71" Name="male" Width="154" />
 <RadioButton Canvas.Left="139" Canvas.Top="207"  FontStyle="Italic" GroupName="Gender" Foreground="Black" Content="Female" Height="71" Name="fem" Width="140" />
```

Now i want to send these data to a web method registertoteam which contains these fields in the following way:

name, street_address, city_address, zip_code, email_address, phone_no, age, gender

I wrote the following code in the submit button.

```
 private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (name.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
            name.Focus();
        }

        if (age.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the age");
            age.Focus();
        }

        if (male.IsChecked == true)
        {
            string gender = male.Content.ToString();
        }
        else if (fem.IsChecked == true)
        {
            string gender = fem.Content.ToString();
        }
        else    //none of them is selected.
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please select your Gender");
        }

        if (sadd.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Street Address");
            sadd.Focus();
        }

        if (cadd.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the City Address");
            cadd.Focus();
        }

        if (eadd.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Email Address");
            eadd.Focus();
        }

        if (phn.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Phone Number");
            phn.Focus();
        }

        if (zip.Text == String.Empty)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Zipcode");
            zip.Focus();
        }

        else
        {
           var svc = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
           svc.registerToTeamAsync(name.Text, sadd.Text, cadd.Text, zip.Text, eadd.Text, phn.Text, age.Text);
        }

}
```

In the else part i want the code to submit the data in that webmethod i.e registertoteam. The code that i wrote in the else part is not working and also have errors. Please edit my code in the else part so that the data gets submitted. Thanks

Comment: what kind of error, compile-time or run-time error? and the error message?

Comment: @har07 compile time error. Is this the correct method i am doing? i got this help from you months ago. Actually i am not in office now so not able to post the errors exactly. Can u please help me in this regard. All the codes that you wrote for me so far worked absolutely fine. Can you plz write the code that i should put in the else part

Comment: No one can write a working code for use in that part without knowing the web service / can call it. It is a guess work (I did it in your previous question regarding this problem). At least let me know the service address

Comment: @har07 The service address is:  http://ws.clearwintech.com/aap.asmx and the address of registertoteam is:  http://ws.clearwintech.com/aap.asmx?op=registerToTeam

Comment: @har07 please see my service address and try to fix my issue.

Comment: tested, no problem with web service, no problem with the way you call service method. if the problem is `registerToTeamAsync` is not recognized, try to update your service reference or even delete and add it again to the project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine. I tested this way :

```
var svc = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
svc.registerToTeamAsync("har07", "addr", "city", "zip", "email", "000", "2", "a");
svc.registerToTeamCompleted += (o, args) =>
                               {
                                   MessageBox.Show("Registration Successful");
                                   var result = args.Result;
                               };
```

No error, and running the same code for 2nd time causes web service to return "emailExists" message in `args.Result`. That confirmed data from the 1st run saved successfully so that I can't submit again with the same data.

**UPDATE :**

Updated with *exact* code :

```
private void submit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var gender = "";
    var isValid = ValidateInput(out gender);
    if(isValid)
    {
        var svc = new KejriwalService.aapSoapClient();
        svc.registerToTeamAsync(name.Text, sadd.Text, cadd.Text, 
                            zip.Text, eadd.Text, phn.Text, age.Text, gender);
    }
}

private bool ValidateInput(out string gender)
{
    gender = "";
    if (name.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the name");
        name.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (age.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the age");
        age.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (male.IsChecked == true)
    {
        gender = male.Content.ToString();
    }
    else if (fem.IsChecked == true)
    {
        gender = fem.Content.ToString();
    }
    else    //none of them is selected.
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please select your Gender");
        return false;
    }
    if (sadd.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Street Address");
        sadd.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (cadd.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the City Address");
        cadd.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (eadd.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Email Address");
        eadd.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (phn.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Phone Number");
        phn.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    if (zip.Text == String.Empty)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please Enter the Zipcode");
        zip.Focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you please write the exact code once that i should put in the else part. Moreover Gender field has a radio button so i am not sure how to put that.